# Создание запроса при нажатии "Enter" в поле ввода

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой скрипт:

```js
$(function() {
    var availableTags = ["League of Legends", "Hearthstone: Heroes of Warcraft", "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive", "Dota 2", "Destiny", "Super Mario Maker", "Gaming Talk Shows", "Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain", "Diablo III: Reaper of Souls", "World of Warcraft", "StarCraft II", "H1Z1", "World of Tanks", "Smite", "FIFA 16", "ArmA III", "Rocket League", "Heroes of the Storm", "Dungeons & Dragons", "RuneScape", "Minecraft", "Gears of War: Ultimate Edition", "Music", "DayZ", "Creative", "Blood Bowl 2", "RPG Maker", "Poker", "Grand Theft Auto V", "Warframe", "Path of Exile", "World of Warships", "Layers of Fear", "Madden NFL 16", "Dark Souls", "Games + Demos", "The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time", "RimWorld", "Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare", "Magic: The Gathering", "Shovel Knight", "Pokémon Omega Ruby/Alpha Sapphire", "Guild Wars 2", "The Binding of Isaac: Rebirth", "ARK: Survival Evolved", "Team Fortress 2", "Battlefield 4", "Until Dawn", "Super Mario 64", "Lineage II: The Chaotic Chronicle", "M.U.G.E.N", "Call of Duty: Black Ops II", "Heroes of Newerth", "Mortal Kombat X", "Halo: The Master Chief Collection", "Rust", "Clash of Clans", "Metal Gear Solid 3: Subsistence", "Kirby Air Ride", "Oddworld: Abe's Oddysee New 'n' Tasty!", "Bloodborne", "Black Desert", "Final Fantasy XIV: Heavensward", "The Elder Scrolls Online: Tamriel Unlimited", "One Piece Treasure Cruise", "Agar.io", "Pokémon Battle Revolution", "Osu!", "Rugrats: Search for Reptar", "Vainglory", "Pokémon Gold/Silver", "Mad Max", "Prime World", "Ultra Street Fighter IV", "Broken Sword: The Serpent's Curse", "Terraria", "War Thunder", "I Wanna Be The Boshy", "Quiplash", "Dark Souls II: Scholar of the First Sin", "Tibia", "MapleStory", "StarCraft: Brood War", "Blade and Soul", "Heroes of Might and Magic III: The Shadow of Death", "Elite: Dangerous", "Warcraft III: The Frozen Throne", "ArcheAge", "Pro Evolution Soccer 2016", "Forza Motorsport 6", "Summoners War: Sky Arena", "Farming Simulator 15", "The Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess", "BioShock", "Battlefield Hardline", "Banjo-Tooie", "Splatoon", "Star Citizen", "Kantai Collection", "Super Smash Bros. for Wii U" ];    
    $("#tags").autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
});
```

```html
<div class="ui-widget">
    <form method="GET" action="">
        <label for="tags">Введите начало названия игры: </label>
        <input id="tags">
        <u>
    </form>
</div>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Не могу понять что делаю не так: хочу, чтобы при нажатом ENTER в `<input id="tags">` создавало запрос *www.my.ru/search.php?q=(тут строка введенная в `<input id="tags">`)*.

Comment: его и нет. И я голову сломал, что бы его сделать. Никогда не кодил раньше, извеняйте. Помогите?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Заполните `action` формы и укажите имя параметра (`q`).

```js
$(function() {
    var availableTags = ["League of Legends", "Hearthstone: Heroes of Warcraft", "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive", "Dota 2", "Destiny", "Super Mario Maker", "Gaming Talk Shows", "Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain", "Diablo III: Reaper of Souls", "World of Warcraft", "StarCraft II", "H1Z1", "World of Tanks", "Smite", "FIFA 16", "ArmA III", "Rocket League", "Heroes of the Storm", "Dungeons & Dragons", "RuneScape", "Minecraft", "Gears of War: Ultimate Edition", "Music", "DayZ", "Creative", "Blood Bowl 2", "RPG Maker", "Poker", "Grand Theft Auto V", "Warframe", "Path of Exile", "World of Warships", "Layers of Fear", "Madden NFL 16", "Dark Souls", "Games + Demos", "The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time", "RimWorld", "Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare", "Magic: The Gathering", "Shovel Knight", "Pokémon Omega Ruby/Alpha Sapphire", "Guild Wars 2", "The Binding of Isaac: Rebirth", "ARK: Survival Evolved", "Team Fortress 2", "Battlefield 4", "Until Dawn", "Super Mario 64", "Lineage II: The Chaotic Chronicle", "M.U.G.E.N", "Call of Duty: Black Ops II", "Heroes of Newerth", "Mortal Kombat X", "Halo: The Master Chief Collection", "Rust", "Clash of Clans", "Metal Gear Solid 3: Subsistence", "Kirby Air Ride", "Oddworld: Abe's Oddysee New 'n' Tasty!", "Bloodborne", "Black Desert", "Final Fantasy XIV: Heavensward", "The Elder Scrolls Online: Tamriel Unlimited", "One Piece Treasure Cruise", "Agar.io", "Pokémon Battle Revolution", "Osu!", "Rugrats: Search for Reptar", "Vainglory", "Pokémon Gold/Silver", "Mad Max", "Prime World", "Ultra Street Fighter IV", "Broken Sword: The Serpent's Curse", "Terraria", "War Thunder", "I Wanna Be The Boshy", "Quiplash", "Dark Souls II: Scholar of the First Sin", "Tibia", "MapleStory", "StarCraft: Brood War", "Blade and Soul", "Heroes of Might and Magic III: The Shadow of Death", "Elite: Dangerous", "Warcraft III: The Frozen Throne", "ArcheAge", "Pro Evolution Soccer 2016", "Forza Motorsport 6", "Summoners War: Sky Arena", "Farming Simulator 15", "The Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess", "BioShock", "Battlefield Hardline", "Banjo-Tooie", "Splatoon", "Star Citizen", "Kantai Collection", "Super Smash Bros. for Wii U" ];    
    $("#tags").autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
});
```

```html
<div class="ui-widget">
  <form method="GET" action="http://www.my.ru/search.php">
      <label for="tags">Введите начало названия игры: </label>
      <input name="q" id="tags">
  </form>
</div>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```